# How many copies did Risk's original 1959 version sell?

Tags: risk

How many copies did the original version of 1959 of the board game [Risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_(game)) sell?

I found [this article](http://www.thehistoryreader.com/modern-history/risk/) stating that it sold more than 100,000 copies in its first year. However there are no sources given from where this information is from.

Answer (score -2):

La Storia di Risiko! e l'Anello Mancante, book by Roberto Convenevole and Francesco Bottyone, estimated 40.000.000 copies sold worldwhide from the beginning to the release of their book, which was in 2002.

Comment: How does this answer the question?